# RoR email with 4th edition book

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with the book 4th edition and I have finish the sending confirmation emails part but when i am in the browser for testing it I have a problem when I place the order..in the book in this(Figure 12.2: Our checkout screen)

ActionView::MissingTemplate in Orders#create Showing c:/Sites/final/app/views/notifier/order_received.text.erb where line #7 raised:

Missing partial line_items/line_item with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "c:/Sites/final/app/views"

Extracted source (around line #7):

```
4: 
5: You ordered the following items:
6: 
7: <%= render @order.line_items %> 
8:
9: We'll send you a separate e-mail when your order ships.
```

Rails.root: c:/Sites/final

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace app/views/notifier/order_received.text.erb:7:in _app_views_notifier_order_received_text_erb___555088091_31657836' app/mailers/notifier.rb:12:inorder_received' app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:58:in block in create' app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:54:increate'

any ideas???

Comment: Please indent your source code examples with four spaces for proper formatting. It makes your question much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an Orders view template for your create action. But you probably don't want a template for the view--you probably want to redirect to another action, depending on success or failure. Something like:

```
def create
  @person = Person.new(params[:person])
  if @person.save
    redirect_to @person, :notice => 'You successfully created person'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: the problem is in order_controller
def create
@order = Order.new(params[:order])
@order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
respond_to do |format|
if '@order.save'
Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
session[:cart_id] = nil
Notifier.order_received('@order').deliver
#....

when i remove the Notifier.oder_received(@order).deliver is working fine but i am not receiving email.. any idea?

Comment: @marios Can you show more of the code, such as '.order_received'? Can you confirm that your email sending works properly?

Comment: order_received is in mailer>notifire and is:
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'kosh ruby <kosiaris8884@gmail.com>'
  def order_received(order)
   ' @order = order'
    mail :to =>  order.email, :subject => 'Koshbay Store Order Confirmation'
  end
  def order_shipped(order)
'@order = order'
mail :to =>  order.email, :subject => 'Koshbay Store Order Shipped'
end
end

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with <%= render @order.line_items %> !
i remove it and is working perfect and receiving emails!